# can't retrive raw post data using file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents, postman

this is my code. and i am posting my data using post method.

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
if(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST'){
    print_r( array( "3","3d"));
}
print_r($post_body);
```

i am using chrome's postman to test this code,but it don't print post data, see output image.

[image: output image]

what i am doing wrong???

**EDIT**

To show how i solve my problem i am adding this image.

[image: To show]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

> `php://input` is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

*Postman* supports different types of `Content-Type` including `multipart/form-data` which seems to be default.

So make sure you don't use `multipart/form-data`(in the `Body` tab).

Comment: it was not `multipart/form-data` error but your answer give me clue to solve my problem thanks

Comment: I still have the same problem. @Archish Please tell me the solution that you did.

Comment: @boi_echos are you using postman ?? if yes then json (which i am passing in question ) should be pass in body tag.i was passing json if wrong tab.

Comment: @boi_echos I've attach image in my question, just doing this my error was solved, i am not sure if this helps you. if you create new question then tell me in comment I've try to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

I had similar trouble testing symfony endpoint but with completely different cause:

My class had only functions in it. And i did a

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

on the first line of my function, which happens to be the first function in the class. This was returning empty("") even if parameters were correct.

My problem was that i forgot to use the FULL route to this, but since postman tried to run this function anyway got me too much time to notice. 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using `api.example.fr/api.php` instead of `https://api.example.fr/api.php`. Try to use the full link of your api.